# What are the odds of losing a bet 20 times in a row when I have a 49.95% chance of winning?

Tags: probability

I have been trying to figure this out, and I can't find anything online that will help me.

What I have to do, is figure out the odds of losing a bet 20 times in a row when I have a 49.95% chance of winning.
I did 2 x 2 20 times, and came out with just over 1,050,000.
Is that the correct amount?

Thanks

Comment: Rounding errors, rounding errors everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each bet is assumed to be an independent and identically distributed Bernoulli trial with probability of winning equal to $p = 0.4995$, then the probability of losing all $20$ bets out of $n = 20$ trials is $$(1-p)^{20} = (1-0.4995)^{20} \approx 9.7293 \times 10^{-7}.$$ or slightly more rare than $1$ in $1027823$.

Comment: Thanks... I'm not really good at p = x and y = z, so thanks for giving me the odds. I'll accept when I can

Answer (score 2):

$49.95\%$, assuming no ties are allowed, means your chance of losing is $50.05\%$.
That means in standard probability notation $p=0.5005$.

Losing $20$ times in a row therefore is $p^{20} = 0.5005^{20} = 9.72930093 \cdot 10^{-7}$ (pretty low)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 49.95% chance of winning, then you have a 50.05% chance of losing. Given independent events, which non-rigorously means that losing bet #1 has no bearing on bet #2, the probability of both events happening is the product of their individual probabilities. In this case, to lose 20 times in a row, you need to calculate $.5005^{20}$.

More precisely, this is a binomial distribution with $n = 20$ trials, $k = 20$ successes (where a success is losing the bet), and $p = 0.5005$ is the probability of a success (lost bet). The formula for a specific binomial probability is:
$$
\textrm{Binomial}(n, k, p) = {n \choose k}p^k\left(1 - p\right)^{n-k}
$$
Substitute the numbers and you see you get $.5005^{20}$

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing really special about winning or losing here. Because the probabilities of winning or losing are very nearly identical (very close to $\frac12$), the probability of ANY specific sequence of twenty outcomes is extremely close to $(\frac12)^{20} \approx 0.00000095367431640625$.

This is simply because there are a huge number of possible outcomes ($2^{20}=1,048,576$ to be exact) so they are all individually equally very unlikely.